# permute 2 groups such that at least one object of the third group separates them

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> There're 9 fiction books and 6 textbooks on a shelf. What is the probability that fiction books will be organized in two groups: a group of 6 books and a group of 3 books and at least one textbook will separate them?

First the total number to organize the books on the shelf is $15!$.

We can now calculate the possibilities to organize fiction books in two groups regardless if there's a textbook that separates between them or not. First choose the books into 2 subgroups: $\binom{9}{3}$. The first subgroup of $3$ can be permuted in $3!$ ways the second subgroup can be permuted in $6!$ ways. Finally because there're $8!$ arrangements on the shelf (2 subgroups of fiction books and textbooks) which gives us in total: 
$$
\binom{9}{3}3!6!8!
$$
Now we can calculate the number of arrangements when the subgroups of fiction are always together:
$$
2!\binom{9}{3}3!6!7!
$$
($2!$ because the subgroup of $3$ fiction books can be to the left or to the right, likewise the group of $6$; 7! because now fiction books are  one "block"). Hence the total number of arrangements given the restrictions above is:
$$
\binom{9}{3}3!6!8! - 2!\binom{9}{3}3!6!7!
$$

Please let me know if my logic is correct.

Comment: Are you getting a write answer?

Comment: I don't know what the correct answer is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an independent approach to getting the result, start with the $6$ textbooks and insert the group of $6$ fiction books into one gap, then the group of $3$ fiction books into another. There are seven gaps to start with - five between textbooks and one at each end - then six for the second choice, so this insertion can be achieved in $\binom 71\binom 61 = 7\times 6 =42$ ways. Then permute the various books in their categories:

$$9!6!42$$

And for a probability compare to the total permutations:

$$\frac{9!6!42}{15!} = \frac{7\cdot6^2\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2}{15\cdot14\cdot13\cdot12\cdot11\cdot10}=\frac{6}{13\cdot11\cdot5}=\frac{6}{715}$$

Comment: gotcha, nice strategy!

Comment: It's important that the group of six is (intrinsically) distinct from the group of three. If we were (for example) inserting three groups of $3$, those aren't distinct (at this point) and the relevant number would be $\binom 73$ rather than $\binom 71\binom 61\binom 51$